# Switch-case in haxe

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I have a problem with my haxe code, So I have the following code :

```
var t : String = switch( id ) {
        case 1 : Std.random( 2 ) == 0 ? Texts.list.0 : Texts.list.1;
        case 2 : Std.random( 2 ) == 0 ? Texts.list.2 : Texts.list.3;
        default: "";
    }
```

For the default I get an error : `This pattern is unused`.
Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is due that compiler detects patterns which will never match the input value http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-unused.html

In this case it might be bug https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4387
if You use haxe 3.2, try 3.1.3 to ensure.

In try.haxe your sample works well http://try.haxe.org/#9e54A